# Reference Error while debugging

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging

In the geth console attached to localhost:

> debug.traceTransaction("Transaction hash"); ReferenceError: 'debug' is
>   not defined     at :1:1

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable the debug api

> geth --rpc --rpcapi eth,web3,**debug**,admin,net ....